# sublime.log_commands(True) for vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

In SublimeText you can open the console and enter `sublime.log_commands(True)` to force sublime to log every single command which is ran by the editor. It helps a lot to understand what's going on and to find out which commands you should do your key binding on.

I just want to know if there's something similar in VSCode?

Comment: I do not think vscode supports such a command. Have you considered opening a new [feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new)? When the [extension logging](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20#_extension-logging) is available you could write your own extension that provides that feature.

Answer (score 1):

In update 1.20.1 available logs:

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20#_output-panel

Extension logging:

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20#_extension-logging

Commands (see log commands):

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20#_new-commands

For example tap `Ctrl + P`:

then `>` and printing:

`Developer: Open Logs Folder`

`Developer: Show Logs...`

... and other commands.